# Pushing to Artifactory using Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I'm pushing the artifacts using:

```
stage('push_to_Artifactory') {
     def server = Artifactory.server 'Artifactory'
    url: 'http://artfact_URL', username: 'userid', password: 'swd'
def uploadSpec = 
"""
{
"files": [
    {
        "pattern": "*/target/*.jar",
        "target": "SCA_Test"
    },
     {
        "pattern": "*/target/*.ear",
        "target": "SCA_Test"
      }

  ]
}"""
server.upload(uploadSpec)
```

}

This is working fine for me but

1) It didn't follow any structure. There's no version information and no POMs or xml files.

2) When I add the Buildinfo code that is

```
    def buildInfo1 = server.download(downloadSpec)

def buildInfo2 = server.upload(uploadSpec)

buildInfo1.append(buildInfo2)

server.publishBuildInfo(buildInfo1)
```

**getting below error**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.git.util.BuildData
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1374)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1327)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1080)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.extractVcsBuildData(Utils.java:121)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.BuildInfoDeployer.addVcsDataToBuild(BuildInfoDeployer.java:63)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.BuildInfoDeployer.<init>(BuildInfoDeployer.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo.createDeployer(BuildInfo.java:212)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfoAccessor.createDeployer(BuildInfoAccessor.java:75)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:148)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.ArtifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo(ArtifactoryServer.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/plugins/git/util/BuildData
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.Utils.extractVcsBuildData(Utils.java:121)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.BuildInfoDeployer.addVcsDataToBuild(BuildInfoDeployer.java:63)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.BuildInfoDeployer.<init>(BuildInfoDeployer.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfo.createDeployer(BuildInfo.java:212)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.buildInfo.BuildInfoAccessor.createDeployer(BuildInfoAccessor.java:75)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:59)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.steps.PublishBuildInfoStep$Execution.run(PublishBuildInfoStep.java:39)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.start(AbstractSynchronousStepExecution.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:222)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:148)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.pipeline.types.ArtifactoryServer.publishBuildInfo(ArtifactoryServer.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:146)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:16)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:53)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor198.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:76)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:173)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:162)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:162)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:35)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:32)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:82)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:242)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:230)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

please help me with the above 2 issues.

Answer (score 4):

You are currently deploying artifacts in a generic way, which means that you are simply deploying the files matching the file spec to Artifactory. This will work fine, but as you mentioned will not have anything Maven specific.
If you wish to run Maven builds using the Artifactory plugin pipeline support you should follow the instructions for [Maven Builds with Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-MavenBuildswithArtifactory).

The stacktrace indicates that you are missing the [Jenkins git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git%20Plugin). Installing the plugin should resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks @Dror Bereznitsky  that worked fine. could you please tell me how do I attach Jenkins build_number to maven artifacts name while pushing to artifactory. how do I configure my Jenkins pipeline script?

Comment: the above configuration is pushing the artifacts with timestamp but I want to add buildnumber aswell